# How to loop through multiple autofilter criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a loop for the auto filter criteria field. `Criteria1=07` should go to 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, then I want `criteria2` to increment to 2015 and `criteria1` to start back at 01 to 12 then `criteria2` to increment to 2016 and so on.

Here is code from my non-looped version:

```
'07 & 2014
ActiveSheet.Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="=07*", _
    Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="=*2014"
Range([D2], Cells(Rows.Count, "D")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-409]mmm-yy;@"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "7/1/2014"
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.FillDown

'08 & 2014
ActiveSheet.Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="=08*", _
    Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="=*2014"
Range([D2], Cells(Rows.Count, "D")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-409]mmm-yy;@"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "8/1/2014"
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.FillDown

'09 & 2014
ActiveSheet.Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="=09*", _
    Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="=*2014"
Range([D2], Cells(Rows.Count, "D")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-409]mmm-yy;@"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "9/1/2014"
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.FillDown
```

How do I use a loop to simplify this code?

Comment: And? Please don't just post a block of a code with no follow up... Please read up on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm unsure on what you're trying to do. Could you explain a bit more on what you are trying to do.

Comment: So as you can see in the code constantly repeats its just the criteria changes each time. Im trying to figure out how to perform a  Do while of if then loop where the criteria changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have two sets of criteria to run through you need a double loop, one loop inside another.  First start with looping through the year and inside that, loop through the month.  You then have two problems to overcome, the leading zero on single digit months and the integer to string conversion.

Here is a sample to get you started.  Note that I did **not** test this and I'd advise you working from a *copy* of your workbook since there is no undo with macros in Excel.

```
Sub test()
    Dim cr1 As String
    Dim cr2 As String
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    For j = 2014 To 2017
        For i = 1 To 12
            cr1 = "=" + Format(cr1, "00") + "*"  'Account for leading zero
            cr2 = "=*" + CStr(j)

            ActiveSheet.Range("A:E").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=cr1, _
    Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:=cr2
            Range([D2], Cells(Rows.Count, "D")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Select
            Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-409]mmm-yy;@"
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = CStr(i) + "/1/2014"
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
            Selection.FillDown
        Next i
    Next j
End Sub
```